# Multilanguage default opening in php

Tags: php, multilingual

I have faced a problem. The code writes in the html body parts. I want the site to come up as by default when the site is opened. At the moment I click on these codes and it shows up when I click on the page and click on the page again. I want the page to always open in **English by default**.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_GET['lang']) {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
        header("Location:index.php"); 
    }

    if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") {
        $lang= "en";
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == "gr") {
        $lang= "gr";
    }
    else {
        $lang= substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
    }
    include 'languages/'.$lang.'.php';
?>
```

Comment: use cookies instead of session

Comment: yes can that method

Answer (score 0):

"I want the page to always open in English by default"

Does this do the trick?

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

By default `$lang= substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);` will work. If you want by default English then change this to `$lang= "en"`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

Comment: Maybe you have a $_SESSION['lang'] declared beforehand. Try from new session.